# Sorting array of dictionaries starting from a specific value

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects (dictionaries) which contain a key `@"Category"`. I have to sort it by a specific key starting by that key. For example if the values in the `objects[@"Category"]: A, B ,C ,D ,E ,F ,G , H etc.` and the user selects "sort by C" I need to reorder the root array by the object which `[@"Category"]` to: C,D,E,F,G,H,A,B -or- C,A,B,D,E,F,G,H .

I hope it is clear what my goal is. I tried:

```
//    sortedPosts2 = [self.objects sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(PFObject *object1, PFObject *object2)  {
//            return [object1[@"Category"] compare:object2[@"Category"] options:NSOrderedAscending];
//    }];


//    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:category ascending:YES];
//    sortedPosts2 = [self.objects sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];


    [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
}
```

Comment: Nothing in your code seems to deal with the selected sort item...

Comment: sortDescriptorWithKey:category where category is a string selected by the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of would be a sorting block.  Then you can do manual adjustments to the array compare values.  This should work for any size string in `Category`.  You may need to change around greater than signs or Ascending/Descending returns, I always get mixed up with ascending/descending...

```
NSArray *array;
NSString *userSelectedValue = @"C";
array = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSString *category1 = [[(NSDictionary*)obj1 objectForKey:@"Category"] lowercaseString];
    NSString *category2 = [[(NSDictionary*)obj2 objectForKey:@"Category"] lowercaseString];

    //Now check if either category's value is less than the user selected value
    NSComparisonResult result1 = [category1 compare:[userSelectedValue lowercaseString]];
    NSComparisonResult result2 = [category2 compare:[userSelectedValue lowercaseString]];

    if(result1 == result2)
    {
        return [category1 compare:category2];
    }
    else if(result1 > result2)
    {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    else
        return NSOrderedAscending;
}];
```